# Capturing Dialog-Windows with SpecFlow

Tags: c#, specflow

I am fairly new to testing still, but have been using SpecFlow for a a few months. I am not entirely sure if what I am going to ask is possible, but maybe someone will have a suggestion to go about the problem.

Synopsis: My feature file makes a call to a method that creates a dialog window stored in a variable created in that method. The user would then need to fill out the dialog window (it is basically picking a file, and then clicking ok). The rest of the method relies on the information provided by the dialog window.

Problem: Since the window is created in the method and the result is stored in a variable created at that moment, I can not provide my information into the variable. But in order for my behavior tests to finish, I need to provide this information.

Example code:

Feature File:

```
Given I initialize the class
And I click on change selected item
```

Steps File:

```
[Given(@"I initialize the class")]
public void GivenIInitializeTheClass()
{
    DoStuff();
    SomeClass testClass = new SomeClasee();
}

[Given(@"IClickOnChangeSelectedItem")]
public void GivenIClickOnChangeSelectItem()
{
    testClass.ChangeItem();
}
```

Method From Class:

```
public void ChangeItem()
{
    var window = new SomeDialogWindow();
    var result = window.ShowDialog();
    if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
    {
        NewItem = window.SelectedItem;
    }
}
```

I would know how to go about this if I could change the method in the class, but, in this example, I can make no changes to the class itself. Again I do not know if it is possible to assign anything to the result, or control the window since the variables for both are created within the method.

Comment: SO if I understand you correctly you want to be able to set the value of `NewItem` from your test? Is `NewItem` public in the test class?

Comment: No it is not. Sorry should have included that to begin with. As I research more and more, I feel as if this is an impossible task, and my only recourse is to get the product code changed to become testable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do this is quite a common pattern and fairly easy to solve, but first lets consider what kind of testing you might want to be running.

Unit tests - In a unit test that only wants to test the implementation of `SomeClass` we don't care about the implementation of other classes including `SomeDialogWindow`. Alternatively we could be writing tests that care solely about the implementation of `SomeDialogWindow`, or even just the implementation of `SomeClass::ChangeItem` and nothing else. How fine do you want to go? These tests are there to pinpoint exactly where some of your code is broken.

Acceptance tests - We build these to test how everything works together. They do care about the interaction between different units and as such will show up things that unit tests don't find. Subtle configuration issues, or more complicated interactions between units. Unfortunately they cover huge swathes of code, so leave you needing something more precise to find out what is wrong.

In a *Test driven* development project, we might write a single acceptance test so we can see when we are done, then we will write many unit tests one at a time, each unit test used to add a small piece of functionality to the codebase, and confirm it works before moving to the next.

**Now for how to do it**. As long as you are able to modify `SomeClass` its not a huge change, in fact all you really need is to add `virtual` to the `ChangeItem` method to make

```
public virtual void ChangeItem()
...
```

What this now allows you do is to replace the method with a different implementation when you are testing it. In the simplest form you can then declare something like,

```
namespace xxx.Tests
{
  public class TestableSomeClass : SomeClass
  {
    public Item TestItem {get;set;}
    public override void ChangeItem()
    {
      NewItem = TestItem;
    }
  }
}
```

This is a very common pattern and known as a stub. We've reduced the functionality in `ChangeItem` down to its bare essentials so its just a minimal stub of its original intent. We aren't testing `ChangeItem` anymore, just the other parts of our code.

In fact this pattern this pattern is so common there are libraries there to help us to *Mock* the function instead. I tend to use one called Moq and it would now look like this.

```
//Given
var desiredItem = ...
Mock<SomeClass> myMock = new Mock<SomeClass>();
myMock.Setup(x=>x.ChangeItem).Returns(desiredItem);
var testClass = myMock.Object;
//When 
testClass.ChangeItem();
//Then
testClass.NewItem.ShouldEqual(....);
```

You will notice that in both these examples we have gotten rid of the GUI part of the codebase so that we can concentrate on your functionality. I would personally recommend this approach for getting 90% to get your codebase covered and end up with rapid uncomplicated testing. However sometimes you need *Acceptance tests* that even test the UI, and then we come to an altogether more complicated beast.

For eaxmple, your UI will include blocking calls when it displays the visual elements, such as `SomeDialogWindow.ShowDialog()` and these have to occur on what is commonly referred to as the `UI thread`. Fortunately while only one thread can be the UI thread, any thread can be the UI thread if it gets there first, but you will need to have at least one thread displaying the UI and another running the tests. You can steal a pattern from web based testing and create driver classes that control your UI, and these will end up on the test running thread performing the click operations and polling to see if the operations are complete.

If you need to go to these lengths then don't start with this as you learn how to use the testing frameworks, start with the simple stuff.